# How to Install InfluxDB in Google App Engine python project?

Tags: python, linux, google-app-engine, pip, influxdb

I want to add influxdb-python https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-python to my app-engine project . But using `$ pip install influxdb`
would only install it on the local machine.
How should I install it as a library to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the library to your root directory, alongside `app.yaml`. Then import it normally:

```
import influxdb
```

Remember to only copy [the actual](https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-python/tree/master/influxdb) library directory.